# pass 120v through 12v control solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I want to remote control the power going to a water heater on a boat - the water heater is 110v and the remote control voltage is 12v - can I use a 12v continuous use solenoid to pass the 120v - I am looking at using a continuous 200 amp solenoid the switching voltage is of course 12v, but can 120v be run throught it - have not been able to find a 12v solenoid that says rated for AC

Answer (score 1):

In a relay
a) The current rating depends on the size of the contacts and flexible wires to them.
b) The voltage rating depends on the thickness of the insulation between contacts and casing+coil, and the quality of the build.

'200Amp' sounds like a relay with low voltage high current contacts. Without any further information (what's written on it, photograph, part number, contact voltage rating even), it sounds like like it is **not** rated for 120v, and you will be putting your safety at risk if you connect that voltage to it.

In a 'low voltage' relay, it is assumed that the applied voltage will be below the 'touch safe' limit of 40/50ish volts, and no attention will have been paid to making the relay safe if high voltages are applied.

Assume that if no voltage is written on it for contact rating, it is not safe above 50v.

Answer (score 1):

The high-current solenoids that we use for switching battery power on boats and RVs are not suitable for handling 120 VAC.

I haven't noticed relays suitable for switching 120 VAC at my local marine suppliers, so you may have to go to an elecrical/electronic supplier like DigiKey to find a suitable relay for your application.  You need a relay with a 12 volt coil, and contacts rated at 120V AC, 15 Amp, or more.

Comment: The information is what was hoped for, but no matter where I search I can not find that type of relay. Just spent last hour looking. Any Sugestions

Comment: Did you try a search at Digikey?  I found http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/LY1-DC12/Z785-ND/126853  and several others.

Comment: Peter Thank you for the input, but I need it in a solenoid not a relay, this will mount on the bulkhead of a boat. It appears that what I need does not exist, I sure have looked everywhere. Also, I need the capability for 20 amps

Comment: The relay I sugggested can mount in a socket that could be mounted to the bulkhead.